# TokuDB/InnoDB Question

Tags: mysql, innodb, tokudb

What's the faster scheme for insert data to `TokuDB` or `InnoDB` Engine? Over 200 Insert per second.

That's okay to answer of one engine.

```
TABLE: `game`
`gameId` bigint 20 (PK)
`gameMapId` int 4
`gameType` varchar 20
`createDate` datetime (index)
```

---

```
TABLE: `game`
`idx` bigint 20 (autoincrement PK)
`gameId` bigint 20 (UK)
`gameMapId` int 4
`gameType` varchar 20
`createDate` datetime (index)
```

Comment: Have you tested them?

Comment: Why would you add just another unique key to an already existing one?  Is `gameId` subject to changes?

Comment: @ypercube Yes, I did test, but I can't know effect because other service are running in same system.

Comment: @dezso `gameID` is unique value. will never be changed.

Answer (score 1):

Percona has already done some benchmarks with TokuDB vs InnoDB

See my post from 10 days ago : [TokuDB not much faster than MySQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/41623/tokudb-not-much-faster-than-mysql/41700#41700)

[Better answers are there as well](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/41623/877).

Comment: That's just one query test. Not enough to judge.

Answer (score 1):

The following is valid for both engines (InnoDB and TokuDB).

The first schema will contain two indexes: a clustered primary key index (gameId) and a secondary index (createDate).

The second schema will create three indexes: a clustered primary key index (idx), a unique secondary index (gameId), and a secondary index (createDate).

Therefore, each insert will require more index maintenance for your second proposed table schema.  It will also be larger on disk given the extra index.

Another important factor to keep in mind is that performing searches by gameId will require a single lookup in the first schema, but two lookups in the second schema (one on the gameId index to get PK values, and another on the PK).